# How to detect in CSS if browser is IE 11 or Edge?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I am trying to use grid layouts but IE 11 and Edge(15 and below) don't support current implementation of grids. I been reading you should have a fall back design(usually just your mobile layout) which I would be using flexbox.

I don't really care about anything less than IE 11.

I know I can use the `@supports not (display: grid)` and stick my flexbox code in that block and this would work for Edge but IE 11 does not support the `@support` tag.

I read for IE 11 I can use `@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active)`

but this does not work in edge so I would have to duplicate my flexbox css code twice. Once in the @media check and one in @supports.

I would like to merge the check into one if possible.

Example:

```
/* use this for anything that supports grid layout */
@supports (display: grid){
    .container {
        display: grid; 
    }

}

/* need to wrap this around with something that will only render on IE 11 or Edge 15 and below */
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: maybe the basic would work : `display:flex;display:grid;` If grid is not supported, then flex should not be overridden. ... flex rules set first and only applied when grid is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is grid implementation specifically for IE10, 11 and Edge < 16. Here is how to handle both `IE` and `Grid` supporting browsers:

In your Grid you need to setup both MS grid and New grid:

```
.my-grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: 500px auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 500px auto auto;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 400px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 400px;
}
```

Then you need to use `-ms` vendor prefixes on each of your section as well as regular non prefixed ones. Basically you will implement two grids. If you only want to use flex on `IE` as you mentioned then:

```
.my-grid {
  display: flex;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 500px auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 400px;
  /* since IE doesn't support display: grid; the last two lines won't matter */
}
```

My recommendation is:

1. Mobile first using flex
2. Grid for new grid supported in all major browsers
3. MS Grid (does not support gutters from new grid)

**NOTES**: Microsoft made the first grid implementation, after that other Browsers changed the Spec and after a few years made their own implementation. It took MS a few years to match the new spec on IE Edge 16. That's why there is a MS grid implementation, and a grid one.

Comment: Yep I was suprised to learn that IE came out with it and the other browsers changed it(usually it is the otherway around). Anyways I don't want to deal with the old IE grid specs. I am trying to follow that if your on mobile or not supported browser of grid you will use Flex and grid for everything else. So you can mix and match and it will work? Like does the browser see it does not support grid and then uses display: flex but when it supports grid, flex gets overridden because it was first?

Comment: That's correct @chobo2, the last rule overrides the first, that's the main reason css gets out of hand, people override the override the override, but in your specific case it makes perfect sense.

Since grid may not work in some browsers, your css will default to flex

Comment: I guess though there will be some orphan css tags as if I do flex-direction it won't be overridden by anything by the grid but it just won't do anything as display got overridden.

Comment: @chobo2 you are correct, same for the `grid-column` and `grid-row` that you set that won't be used if it's `flex`.